# Help setting up a Java EE development environment in Windows 7 Ultimate machine

Tags: jakarta-ee

I installed the following in that order:

1. Java Runtime
2. Java SE SDK
3. Netbeans 6.9.1 (which components should I choose?)
4. XAMPP 1.7.3 for the MySQL database server
5. ????

I don't know whether that is enough for developing Java EE applications. What are the things I should install and in what order, so that I can develop Java EE applications? Please give me the links to download because when I search in Google and find the pages, there are many packages for all these things and I can't seem to figure out which one to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stack is IMO a good one for a beginner (because you'll find tons of very didactic tutorials):

- [Java SE JDK 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) as IDE
- [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (or XAMPP, but NetBeans provides a very good SQL client) as database server
- [GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.0.1](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/downloads/3.0.1-final.html) as Java EE 6 application server

Then follow tutorials like:

- [The NetBeans E-commerce Tutorial - Setting up the Development Environment](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/setup-dev-environ.html)
- [Java EE & Java Web Learning Trail](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html) (many of them here)

Once you'll be more familiar with the Java EE platform, it will always be possible to do variations around the base (e.g. another IDE).

Comment: When I generally search for "java 6 jdk" lots of Java SE links come up. But when I specifically searched for "java ee 6 jdk", I got a EE download page - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html Does that page contain the proper Java EE 6 JDK? Is that the JDK you suggested in your first point?

Comment: The links themselves give the location from where I can download the JDK. Thanks for all the links :)

Comment: @Senthil The Java SE JDK is what you need to do Java development (it contains development tools like the javac compiler). GlassFish is a server on which you can run Java EE code. You can get GlassFish as part of a bundle (the "Java EE SDK", or even in some versions of NetBeans) but my suggestion is to install individual components.

Comment: Now I am clear. I need 1)Java SE JDK 2)NetBeans IDE alone 3)GlassFish server alone

Comment: +1.. I have successfully installed the entire set and created a simple web app. The whole thing is working properly. Thanks a lot :) The next hurdle is basic database app..

Comment: @Senthil Glad it was useful. For the next step, no hurdle, just have a look at some tutorials from the above links like [Connecting the Application to the Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/connect-db.html) or [Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html).